# How to cast char* to char *const* in C

Tags: c, casting, char

I am trying to use the execv() function.

I am trying to pass in my argument command to the left side.

```
 execv(file,arguments);
```

I am using a char * to parse the incoming user input for my shell.

The second argument of execv takes a char * const*.

Is there a way I can cast a char * const to a char * const*?

I try this below,

```
char * arg;
char *const a[] = (char *const)arg;

error: invalid initializer
      char *const a[] = (char *const)arg;
                        ^
```

But it does not work and gives me errors.

Help would be apprecieated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error in `char *const a[] = (char *const)arg;` is not due to an improper conversion. It is because `char *const a[]` declares an array, and the initializers for an array must be in braces<sup>1</sup>, `{ … }`, but you have specified just one initializer without braces.

Furthermore, the `argv` parameter to `execv` should be an array of pointers in which the first points to a string containing the file name of the program being executed (this is by convention, not required) and the last is a null pointer. Thus, your definition of `a` ought to be something like:

```
char * const a[] = { FileNameOfProgram, arg, NULL };
```

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> Except when a string literal is used to initialize an array, but that is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to initialize an array. Instead of doing this,

```
char * arg;
char *const a[] = (char *const)arg;
```

do this:

```
char * arg;
char *const a[] = {(char *const)arg};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite normal to do an `execv` after eliminating the command name and some of the first parameters.  For example, if you  have some code like (you had better to post a complete and verifiable example) let's assume you are doing something like this (if you want an example, look for the `xargs(1)` manpage, you have a command, and after processing the options and their parameters, you want to eliminate all of them, and execute the rest as if it was a command line, e.g.  I have a command to execute repeatedly a command, delaying some specified time, like:

```
cont -t 0.1 -- df -k .
```

I use `<getopts.h>`  to process the options of my `cont` program, then execute repeatedly the command `df -k`.  Options allow to show a version for the program, to specify timeout, be verbose, or the number of times to execute the command.  I wrote it just now, to show you how to do it (the example includes `fork(2)` use, `execvp(2)` and  redirection to capture the output of the command to be able to go back to the origin, once known the number of lines we have received, the program uses an ANSI escape to move the cursor back to the beginning.)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define F(_fmt) "%s:%d: " _fmt, __FILE__, __LINE__

#define FLAG_VERBOSE        (1<<0)
#define FLAG_VERSION        (1<<1)
#define FLAG_DELAY          (1<<2)
#define FLAG_NTIMES         (1<<3)

int flags = 0;
useconds_t delay = 1000000;
size_t ntimes;

void doVersion(void)
{
    fprintf(stderr, 
            "cont: v1.0\n"
            "(C) Luis Colorado.  All rights reserved.\n"
            "License: BSD\n");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

ssize_t loop(int argc_unused, char **argv)
{
    int fd[2];
    int res = pipe(fd);

    res = fork();
    if (res < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr,
                    F("fork: ERROR %d: %s\n"),
                    errno,
                    strerror(errno));
            return -1;
    } else if (res == 0) { /* child */
            close(fd[0]); /* not going to use it */
            dup2(fd[1], 1); /* redirect output to pipe */
            close(fd[1]);

            execvp(argv[0], argv);

            fprintf(stderr,
                    F("execv: ERROR %d: %s\n"),
                    errno, strerror(errno));
            return -1;
    } else { /* parent */
            pid_t cld_pid = res;
            close(fd[1]); /* no writing to the pipe */
            FILE *f = fdopen(fd[0], "rt"); /* just reading */
            int c;
            size_t lines = 0;
            while((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
                    if (c == '\n') lines++;
                    putc(c, stdout);
            }
            wait(NULL);
            return lines;
    }

} /* loop */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int opt;
    float t;

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "t:Vvn:")) >= 0) {
            switch(opt) {
            case 't': flags |= FLAG_DELAY;
                              t = atof(optarg);
                              break;
            case 'V': flags |= FLAG_VERSION;
                              break;
            case 'v': flags |= FLAG_VERBOSE;
                              break;
            case 'n': flags |= FLAG_NTIMES;
                              ntimes = atoi(optarg);
                              break;
            /* ... */
            }
    }

    if (flags & FLAG_VERSION)
            doVersion();

    /* the next pair of sentences is like `shift optind' in the shell. */
    /* trick, don't move the parameters, just move the pointer */
    argc -= optind; /* adjust the number of parameters. */
    argv += optind; /* advance the pointer to the proper place */

    /* NOW, argc && argv are identical to the original ones, but lacking the
     * first `optind' argument strings.  As the original string array ended
     * in a NULL, there's no need to construct it from allocating memory.
     * Anyway, we're not going to use after it's consumed in main().  */

    if (flags & FLAG_VERBOSE) {
            char *sep = "About to execute: ";
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s%s", sep, argv[i]);
                    sep = " ";
            }
            fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    }

    if (flags & FLAG_DELAY) {
            delay = t * 1.0E6;
    }

    size_t total_lines = 0;
    ssize_t n = 0;
    while(!(flags & FLAG_NTIMES) || ntimes--) {

            /* move up as many lines as input from subcommand */
            if (n) printf("\r\033[%ldA@\b", n);

            n = loop(argc, argv);

            if (n < 0) {
                    /* we have already written the error */
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            usleep(delay);

            total_lines += n;
    }
    if (flags & FLAG_VERBOSE) {
            fprintf(stderr,
                    F("Total lines: %lu\n"),
                    total_lines);
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

you can download a complete version of this program from [Github](https://github.com/mojadita/cont)